# How to use AceUnit?

Tags: java, c, unit-testing

I want to use *AceUnit framework* for unit test modules. In order to use this framework I have downloaded AceUnit source *aceunit-0.3.2-src.tar* but found No generator *AceUnit.jar* in */src/java*. So, I used independently downloaded AceUnit-0.12.0.jar to make it work.
To test the framework I executed the example sortTest but Test Program *crashed* due to segmentation fault.

#### Is there anybody who have used it already or help me to guide further?

Comment: Why is this question tagged c?

Comment: This question is correctly tagged "c" because AceUnit is a unit test framework for the C programming language. It is also tagged Java because in order to support Annotations and Reflection in C, AceUnit uses an additional parser and header-file generator which is written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a bit of information that hopefully solves the issues for you.

- It is normal that the source code does not contain any binaries. You can build the binaries, including the AceUnit.jar, from the source code.
- aceunit-0.3.2 is unsupported because it is an old version. Please use the latest version.
- Also, the version needs to be consistent. The generator of AceUnit-0.12.0 will not work with aceunit-0.3.2. Please consistently use the same version, i.e. 0.12.0.
- For error reports, please include detailed information: What OS do you use, what compiler do you use etc.. Also, a paste of the terminal window contents or log is useful. That can reduce the number of loops we have to take in order to solve your problem.

I hope this helps and after updating you can run the demos and tests. If you still can't, please provide information like OS, compiler and contents of the terminal window.

The very latest version of AceUnit is currently hosted on Github: https://github.com/christianhujer/aceunit it has more features and should be more convenient to use, although support for some exotic compilers like C51, C251, C166 is currently not tested. But it should work perfectly well with GCC, armcc and clang. Practically, there's currently a segfault on clang which will probably be removed by next week.